# How to gloss lines in a dialogue in one example using gb4e?

Tags: gb4e

It should look like this:

[image]

and this does not work:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{tomatoes}
\gll Abe: Tomaten sind Obst.\\
{} tomatoes are fruit\\
Briselotta: Are you kidding me?\\
\gll Abe: Nein, natürlich nicht.\\
{} no naturally not
\end{exe}
```

Speaker B's line is always fine and makes no difference whatsoever, and speaker A's second statement and intended glosses are fine yet unorderly until the second \gll command is added, making everything that follows within the example disappear in the output (incidentally indenting the entire rest of the text as the example does not end anymore).  (In fact I would be grateful for knowing how to align the sentences following the names, too, as in (1), but oh well.  And the italics I guess I can handle).

Comment: Found a satisfying solution using tables:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a satisfying solution using tables:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.5cm}lll}
    Abe: & \textit{Tomaten} & \textit{sind} & \textit{Obst.}\\
    & tomatoes & are & fruit\\
    \end{tabular}\\
 %
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.5cm}l}
    Briselotta: & Are you kidding me?\\
    \end{tabular}\\
 %
    \begin{tabular}[t]{p{1.5cm}lll}
    Abe: & \textit{Nein,} & \textit{nat\"urlich} & \textit{nicht.}\\
    & no & naturally & not
    \end{tabular}
\end{exe}
```

Looks really nice:

[image]